# Line separators in a GridView in a Windows 8.1 app using XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I would like to create line separators between GridView items similar to the following screenshot of the Bing news app

[image]

GridView XAML. VariableSizedGridView is inherited from GridView but allows items to be of different sizes.

```
<controls:VariableSizedGridView
                    x:Name="newsGridView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding TopItems}"
                    Margin="-9,-14,0,0"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemClick="news_ItemClick"
                    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource mySelector}">
                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemHeight="232" ItemWidth="320" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </controls:VariableSizedGridView>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change  **gridview itemcontainerstyle** If you want line under each Gridview item.for that you need to edit gridviewitem style.

**goto gridview item->right click->Edit template->Edit Copy->Ok.**  and you will get gridview item style

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="Gridvieitemstyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">      
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">                           
                           .
                           .
                        <!--I have removed visualstates.you add it later-->                          
                            .
                            .
                        <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                            <Path x:Name="SelectingGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,9.5,9.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                            <Border x:Name="HintGlyphBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="40" Margin="4" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40">
                                <Path x:Name="HintGlyph" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                                <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="1" Opacity="0"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="4" Opacity="0"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="4">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Text="Xg" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>

                                            <!--I have added this border for each gridview item under line-->
                                            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="5,0,5,5"></Border>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBorder" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource GridViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Height="40" Opacity="0" Width="40">
                                            <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                            <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="13" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="26.667" FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="18,9,0,0" Opacity="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Page.Resources>
 <GridView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Gridvieitemstyle}"></GridView>
```